# Query to Get Multiple y-series for Using ysplit=panels to render multiple panels

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How do I write my query to create the data result in the proper format to be plotted in multiple panels using the `| render timechart with (ysplit=panels)` output?

Looking at Microsoft's examples, I need to have my `IPPrefix` column to produce multiple columns in a single row. Instead, my query is producing separate rows for each grouping in `IPPrefix`.

I have the following query:

```
let startTime = datetime('2020.07.23 20:00:00');
let endTime = datetime('2020.07.23 23:59:00');
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated between (startTime..endTime)
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess"
| where requestUri_s contains "api/auth/ping"
| extend IPParts = split(clientIP_s, '.')
| extend IPPrefix = strcat(IPParts[0], '.', IPParts[1], '.', IPParts[2])
| make-series Count = count() on TimeGenerated in range(startTime, endTime, 5m) by IPPrefix
//| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by IPPrefix, bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
| render timechart with (ysplit=panels)
```

I want the result to look something like:
[image]

But instead, all the y-series are plotted in a single panel like:
[image]

I suppose that I am not using `make-series` in the correct way in order to produce the result I need but I have not been able to apply it in a different way to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that I needed to pivot on the data before rendering. I also learned there is a limit of 5 panels on the `ysplit=panels` option. I had to limit the series to five and then perform a pivot on the aggregated data.

```
...
| make-series Count = count() on TimeGenerated in range(startTime, endTime, 1m) by IPPrefix
| take 5
| evaluate pivot(IPPrefix, any(Count), TimeGenerated)
| render timechart with(ysplit=panels)
```

Resulting chart with five panels.
[image]